# Why does Jenkins unnecessarily change to a different node sometimes?

Tags: jenkins

Why is Jenkins changing node to do another build when it doesn't need to?

We have a Jenkins setup with 3 Mac and 3 Windows nodes, building free style projects. We do not use the master for builds. The projects are set to run on any of the 3 nodes suitable for their platform. We are using labels for this purpose.

Some of the time, when we do a build it will do the build on the same node as last time.
But sometimes, without any obvious pattern, it will change to a different node, even though the previously used node is available and not busy. This wastes a lot of time potentially as incremental builds on the same node are much faster than pulling and building everything from scratch.

Jenkins claims it should allocate jobs to the same node if possible, when multiple possibilities exist.

> As a result, from the user’s point of view, it looks as if Jenkins tries to always use the same node for the same job, unless it’s not available, in which case it’ll build elsewhere. But as soon as the preferred node is available, the build comes back to it. [Reference](https://docs.huihoo.com/jenkins/enterprise/14/user-guide-docs/_default_jenkins_behavior.html)

Jenkins version is 2.289.2 presently.

The jobs are freestyle builds with shell script/command prompt steps.

Repositories are Git and Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you read the `Restrict where this project can be run` that might provide you answer to your question.

As its definition tells `By default, builds of this project may be executed on any agents that are available and configured to accept new builds.`
So if you don't specify the agent and restrict the build to be run a particular node, it will randomly choose.

> This wastes a lot of time potentially as incremental builds on the
> same node are much faster than pulling and building everything from
> scratch.

To solve the above problem only, we have the `Restrict where this project can be run` feature in Jenkins. Please look to the below screenshot for detailed help that we can get in Jenkins .

[image]

Comment: so the overriding means specifying the node in the `Restrict where this project can be run`

Comment: Except that "By default Jenkins tries to allocate a jobs to the last node is was executed on ([ref.](https://docs.huihoo.com/jenkins/enterprise/14/user-guide-docs/_default_jenkins_behavior.html))". So, something is occurring to the OP  overriding that, " even though the previously used node is available and not busy". The question is why, not to override the result.

Comment: Exactly Ian. I don't want to restrict it to just one node, because that means it can't run at all when the node is busy with something else. I just want it to stay on the same node when possible.

Comment: I have clarified that I am expecting Jenkins's documented preference to stay on the same node. I agree that without this doc, the expectation might be that it would just randomly pick one.

Comment: @O'Rooney I have not downvoted. I don't know who has done it.. But Ian document is very interesting and contradicted to what is been written in the Jenkins help . I have upvoted just now , so it will be interesting thing to understand